# If $\{id_V, T, T^2, \ldots, T^d\}$ is linearly independent, then $d<r$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $T$ a linear operator in $V$. I have to show that if $\{id_V, T, T^2, \ldots, T^d\}$ is a linearly independent set, then $d<r$, where $r$ is the number of distinct eigenvalues of $T$.

I think I might use the fact that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is of the form $p=(x-c_1)(x-c_2) \cdots (x-c_r)$, where $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_r$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $T$. I'm not sure of how to use this fact, I'd appreciate any hint to know how to apply this. Thanks in advance.

Edit: $T$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: _If_ you know that the minimal polynomial is of that form then you know that $\{ \mathrm{id}_V, T, T^2, \ldots, T^r \}$ is _not_ linearly independent. But that's a big if.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. For instance, consider the matrix

$$T=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right).$$

Then $\{1, T\}$ is linearly independent, but $r=1$ (the only eigenvalue is $0$).

Comment: I forgot the little detail that $T$ is diagonalizable, that's the only way we can prove that the minimal polynomial is of that form. I guess your last answer was right then.